# How to use multiple result values from a function in R?

Tags: r, function

I have the following code in R:

```
a <- 2
evaluate <- function(x){
  b <- 2*x
  c <- 3*x
  d <- 4*x
  out <- list("b" = b, "c" = c, "d" = d)
  return(out)
}
evaluate(a)
```

I obtain something like

```
$b
[1] 4

$c
[1] 6

$d
[1] 8
```

How can I compute something like b + c + d ?

Comment: `out <- list("b" = b, "c" = c, "d" = d)` should be `out <- sum(b,c,d)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so many options

```
# with
with(evaluate(a), b + c + d)
[1] 18

# unlist the unnamed output object
sum(unlist(evaluate(a)))
[1] 18

# subset a named output object
result <- evaluate(a) 
result$b + result$c + result$d
[1] 18

# subset an unnamed output object
evaluate(a)$b + evaluate(a)$c + evaluate(a)$d
[1] 18

# custom function with fancy arguments
f <- function(...) {
   args <- unlist(...)
   sum(args)
}

f(evaluate(a))
[1] 18
```

Also, +1 from: @Gregor (double-bracket list subsetting)

```
result[["b"]] + result[["c"]] + result[["d"]]
[1] 18
```

Comment: Great! Don't forget `result[["b"]] + result[["c"]] + result[["d"]]`

Comment: Just one more variant if you only wanted to sum a subset of the returned values: `sum(unlist(evaluate(a)[c("b","c","d")]))` but your `with()` option is my favorite.

Comment: For me, it is not important to compute only `b + c + d`. This was only an example. What I wanted was to use b, c, or d in other computations. So making `result <- evaluate(a)` and then using `result$b` is the answer that I needed.

Answer (score 1):

In R you can access list members using $ operator, followed by member name so, in your code, for example:

```
result = evaluate(a)
result$b + result$c + result$d
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a list. You could return a vector and then use the `sum()` function to compute the sum of the elements in the vector. If you must use a list, the 'Reduce()` function can work.

```
l <- list(2, 3, 4)
v <- c(2,3,4)
sum(v) # returns 9
Reduce("+", l) # returns 9
```